# Android getview() returns nothing

Tags: android

im calling my layout and setting items for it but the getview() returns nothing .

My main class :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.MymainView);
        grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        if (getScreenOrientation() == 1)
            grid.setNumColumns(3);
        else
            grid.setNumColumns(4);

        items = new ArrayList<LauncherGridItem>();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        intent.putExtra("Param1", "Child Activity"); 

        items.add(new LauncherGridItem("ic_launcher", "Item 1",
                intent));
    adapter = new LauncherGridAdapter(this, items, grid, dragLayer,
            deleteZone);
    adapter.setPersistenceToken("MyLauncherGrid");
    adapter.setDragListener(this);
    adapter.setEditable(true);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And My LauncherGridAdapter , getview() section in file :

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.grid_view_item_layout, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.selection_item_image);
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.selection_item_text);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            //holder.image.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        DraggableRelativeLayout layout = (DraggableRelativeLayout) convertView;
        convertView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(this);
        LauncherGridItem item = getItems().get(position);

        layout.setItem(item);
        layout.setDragListener(this);
        // holder.image.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        Drawable d = holder.image.getDrawable();
        // if (d != null) {
        d.setCallback(null);
        // }
        holder.image.setImageDrawable(null);
        if (!item.getUrl().startsWith("http")) {

            try {
                holder.image.setImageDrawable(context.getResources()
                        .getDrawable(
                                context.getResources().getIdentifier(
                                        context.getApplicationContext()
                                                .getPackageName()
                                                + ":drawable/" + item.getUrl(),
                                        null, null)));
            } catch (NotFoundException e) {
                holder.image.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_view);
            }
        } else {
//          Image cached = images.get(position);
            if(item.getImage() == null)
            {
                holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar);
            } else {

                holder.image.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
            }
            }
        }
        holder.text.setText(item.getCaption());
        layout.setImage(holder.image);
        layout.setText(holder.text);
        layout.setItem(item);
        layout.canDelete(item.canDelete());
        return convertView;
```

}

i even checked the if statement and program items are valid and not null.
ive also added these but still nothing in gridview :

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return getItems().size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
```

i guess the problem is "grid_view_item_layout" not showing at all

this is the "main" layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#CCCCCC">
    <com.myapp.ui.drag.DragLayer
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:launcher="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.android.launcher"
        android:id="@+id/drag_layer" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_above="@+id/handle">
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="65dip"
            android:background="@color/BlanchedAlmond"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        <com.myapp.ui.drag.DeleteZone
            android:id="@+id/delete_zone_view" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:background="@drawable/delete_zone_bg"
            android:visibility="gone">
            <ImageView android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp" android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/trashcan" />
        </com.myapp.ui.drag.DeleteZone>
    </com.myapp.ui.drag.DragLayer>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and this is grid_view_item_layout layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.myapp.ui.drag.DraggableRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/CadetBlue"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/selection_item_image" android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="60dip" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/selection_item_text"
    android:maxLines="1" android:lines="1" android:scrollHorizontally="true" android:ellipsize="end" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="@android:color/black" 
     android:text="(Selection Text)" android:layout_below="@+id/selection_item_image"  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     ></TextView>
</com.myapp.ui.drag.DraggableRelativeLayout>
```

im using plusgridlayout for moving items between gridview . the function works on source project but when i try to release it under mine no error happen plus no gridview at all.

also if i change the last line of getview() from return convertView;  to return layout; still nothing apears.

Comment: did you extends `BaseAdapter` in `LauncherGridAdapter`?

Comment: yes , here is the start line of code :
public class LauncherGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
  OnLongClickListener, OnClickListener, DragListener,
  DeleteLaunchItemHandler {

Answer (score 4):

you must override `getCount()` method and change the value of return that with size of your list like bellow code:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
     log.d("result of count is",""+items.size())
     return items.size();
}
```

Comment: thanks for method but they where already there and still nothing in gridview

Comment: change getItems() with item(that I think is your list)  in getCount method, and before that log the value to make sure is not empty

Comment: +1 for that. I did not know this but made a test and set the lenght to 0 in my app. The result: nothing is returned

Comment: The item.size return error that such thing as "item" not exist but

Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), Integer.toString(getItems().size()));
this return number of item in grid "4"

Comment: so use that in getCount and return that, `getClass().getSimpleName(), Integer.toString(getItems().size())), did you passed list to this class? what is the name of that?

Comment: and put one log in getView() method to check your app go to that method or not

Comment: this is the source of LauncherGridAdapter :
https://github.com/benmonro/PulseLauncherGrid/blob/master/PulseLauncherGrid/src/com/neudesic/mobile/pulse/ui/launcher/LauncherGridAdapter.java

Comment: did you log on getView method? see my Edit and tell me result of you log

Comment: if i put :
Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), item.toString());
after layout.setItem(item);  in Getview() functions it returns :
4 item in logcat like :
I/LauncherGridAdapter(19268): com.myapp.ui.launcher.LauncherGridItem@40555c70
I/LauncherGridAdapter(19268): com.myapp.ui.launcher.LauncherGridItem@40556388

Comment: see my Edit @nooob, did you see 4 time that log?

Comment: i removed the following line and still nothing happen , and yess log happen 4 time

Answer (score 0):

By default, there will be 4 methods you must override implement in your adapter: `getCount, getItem, getItemId and getView.`

Comment: ive added those but still nothing in gridview